# Process is not within bounds of type-variable T

Tags: java, generics, comparable

I'm trying to compile my project but I get the following error:
"error: type argument Process is not within bounds of type-variable T"

```
public class Heap<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    // ...
}

public class Process {
    // ...
}

public class HeapDemo{
    public static void main(final String[] args) {      
        Heap<Process> heap = new Heap<Process>(); //error here
    }   
}
```

The program is a CPU scheduling simulation using heaps, if that helps any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you get the error is that `Process` does not implement `Comparable<Process>`, a condition that must be met by all classes that you supply as type arguments to `Heap<T>` because of a type constraint that you placed on your generic type.